# circular motion and relative frame of reference

Tags: kinematics, relative-motion, angular-velocity

consider a point O which is center of two circle with radius r and R(r < R). Two particles P and Q are moving on circular path with radius r and R respectively with same constant angular velocity w.how will motion of P appear to Q and how will motion of Q appear to P?

Comment: are you asking us to parametrise the two curves and take their vector difference? :o

Comment: Are the particles rotating around their axes?  Does an observer at O always see the same side of the particle?

Comment: I am asking if an observer is at particle P how will motion of Q appear to it

Answer (score 1):

Let us try to work it out mathematically.
Let the position vector of P be $r(sin(\omega t)\hat{i} + cos(\omega t)\hat{j})$
and that of Q be $R(sin(\omega t +\phi)\hat{i} + cos(\omega t + \phi)\hat{j}) 
$
with respect to $O$.

Thus, the Relative position of Q w.r.t P is:
$(sin(\omega t + \phi)-sin(\omega t))\hat{i} + (cos(\omega t + \phi)-cos(\omega t))\hat{j}$

After plotting it on desmos (https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nlkqpz2dul), we can see that the relative position will always be in a circle, no matter what is the phase difference

Comment: can u please tell the plot when there is no phase difference

Comment: When phi=0, then A=1 and B=0. In this case, the equation becomes (R-r )(sin(ωt)i^+cos(ωt)j^) which is the equation of a circle

Comment: But the distance between two particles is fixed. The first particle should always be able to see second particle at that fixed distance so why is the relative path elliptical? I mean like mathematically it is perfect but I don't get how at fixed relative distance it is elliptical?

Comment: Wait I guess I found what's Mathematically wrong. In the expansion of cos(wt+ o) you forgot the minus sign

Comment: yeah i see it now.... due to this the answer became completely wrong. The relative position will always move along a circle

Comment: I know I am supposed to avoid thanks in comments but man your mathematical approach totally changed my view how  I used to looked at rotation.Now I am able to do many problems previously I was not.So thanks man

Comment: @kishi your welcome! :)